# No Post matches the given query. Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hello everybody I am a newbie in Django and I have started to lear how to create a blog, everything is working fine but when I click post on address http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ I am receiving this

redirection to address >> http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2018/01/07/Django/

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2018/01/07/Django/ Raised by:
>     blog.views.post_detail
>
> No Post matches the given query.

this is a code for views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                             status='published',
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
]
```

Anybody knows why I can not open any post on blog?

Comment: I have the same problem (using Django2 by Example). Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2018/01/07/Django/` is probably not the address you want to be POSTing to.

You likely want to post to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog` and you will use the date from the POST body to save your post.

Either way, this url is not inside your url patterns list, so make sure to add something that routes to "blog" in your patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url('blog/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: Now when I am on and clicking a post then I get an error like this:

Answer (score 0):

Now when I am on http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ and clicking a post then I get an error like this:

> AttributeError at /blog/2018/01/07/Django/
>
> module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'detail'
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2018/01/07/Django/ Django Version:   1.8.6
>   Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:
>
> module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'detail'
>
> Exception Location:   /root/Projekty/mysite/blog/urls.py in ,
>   line 10 Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python3 Python Version:    3.5.2
>   Python Path:
>
> ['/root/Projekty/mysite',  '/usr/lib/python35.zip', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5',  '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>
> Server time:  Mon, 8 Jan 2018 08:35:01 +0000

views.py now looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
    url('blog/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: this is late; but its becuase you do not have "details" in your views.py